# How to install jupyter/docker-stacks with python 2.x

Tags: python-2.7, docker, containers, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to install one of the jupyter containers with python 2.X using docker-stacks.

The documentation at GitHub for jupyter/docker-stacks say:

> Python 2.x was removed from all images on August 10th, 2017, starting in tag cc9feab481f7. If you wish to continue using Python 2.x, pin to tag 82b978b3ceeb.

See:
https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks

I assume you run this as follows to, say for example, install minimal-notebook:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 jupyter/minimal-notebook:82b978b3ceeb
```

But after running I find that python 3.x was installed:

sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Here's the output of the 'docker run' command:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 jupyter/minimal-notebook:82b978b3ceeb
/usr/local/bin/start.sh: line 48: [: missing `]'
/usr/local/bin/start.sh: line 48: : command not found
Execute the command
[I 20:55:49.950 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[W 20:55:49.979 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.
[I 20:55:50.010 NotebookApp] JupyterLab alpha preview extension loaded from /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab
JupyterLab v0.24.1
Known labextensions:
[I 20:55:50.013 NotebookApp] Running the core application with no additional extensions or settings
[I 20:55:50.016 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jovyan
[I 20:55:50.016 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 20:55:50.017 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/?token=f09a12bf53902cb20aca2f1924011e1e80d51243cc10a390
[I 20:55:50.017 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 20:55:50.017 NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=f09a12bf53902cb20aca2f1924011e1e80d51243cc10a390
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a recipe for creating a Python 2 conda environment in `FROM` one of the core images on the GitHub wiki: https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/wiki/Docker-recipes#add-a-python-2x-environment

Comment: Well....I suppose your answer is correct but was missing just one detail.   It turns out my original approach would have worked as well.  Except in both approaches, it turns out both versions of python 2.x and 3.x are installed.  So I just needed to try '/usr/bin/python2' to observe its already installed.

Comment: Following up from previous comment.  Sorry, I forgot what I was trying to do here.  So while the container has both versions but the jupyter notebook still runs with python 3.x as the default.  I would have expected the Dockerfile that you referenced to switch to python 2.x by default.  I suppose I could just figure out how to build a custom image / Dockerfile that does this.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that the [link](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/wiki/Docker-recipes#add-a-python-2x-environment) suggested in [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48591614/7127519) is not there anymore, so I put here the some with some modifications.

You could create the following Dockerfile:

```
# From https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/wiki/Docker-recipes#add-a-python-2x-environment

# Choose your desired base image: you could use another from https://github.com/busbud/jupyter-docker-stacks
FROM jupyter/all-spark-notebook:latest

# Create a Python 2.x environment using conda including at least the ipython kernel
# and the kernda utility. Add any additional packages you want available for use
# in a Python 2 notebook to the first line here (e.g., pandas, matplotlib, etc.)
RUN conda create --quiet --yes -p $CONDA_DIR/envs/python2 python=2.7 ipython ipykernel kernda && \
    conda clean -tipsy

USER root


# Bundle requirements
# You can change the libraries in the file
# requirements.txt
ADD requirements.txt /requirements.txt



# Create a global kernelspec in the image and modify it so that it properly activates
# the python2 conda environment.
RUN $CONDA_DIR/envs/python2/bin/python -m ipykernel install && \
    $CONDA_DIR/envs/python2/bin/kernda -o -y /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2/kernel.json && \
    pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
    rm /requirements.txt && \

USER $NB_USER
```

or if you do not have requirements

```
# From https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/wiki/Docker-recipes#add-a-python-2x-environment

# Choose your desired base image: you could use another from https://github.com/busbud/jupyter-docker-stacks
FROM jupyter/all-spark-notebook:latest

# Create a Python 2.x environment using conda including at least the ipython kernel
# and the kernda utility. Add any additional packages you want available for use
# in a Python 2 notebook to the first line here (e.g., pandas, matplotlib, etc.)
RUN conda create --quiet --yes -p $CONDA_DIR/envs/python2 python=2.7 ipython ipykernel kernda && \
    conda clean -tipsy

USER root



# Create a global kernelspec in the image and modify it so that it properly activates
# the python2 conda environment.
RUN $CONDA_DIR/envs/python2/bin/python -m ipykernel install && \
    $CONDA_DIR/envs/python2/bin/kernda -o -y /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2/kernel.json &

USER $NB_USER
```

Then go to the folder:
To create image:
`docker build -t wm/ubuntupython2jupyterpyspark:v1.0 .`
wm/ubuntupython2jupyterpyspark:v1.0 is just an example you could put another

To run container

`docker run -p 8888:8888  wm/ubuntupython2jupyterpyspark:v1.0`

Comment: I tried it based on the jupyter/scipy-notebook image, it works fine.

Comment: I found pip doesn't install the packages in correct env. I have to use 'conda install -n python2 --file requirement.txt '.